# Spring Thymeleaf not processing field properly?

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an Author class which extends BaseEntity superclass. In the template I'm trying to get a boolean property from the author variable so that I can reuse the form for Create and Update.

Can someone explain the reason what I'm doing wrong and where I can read more into it? I've tried most/all EL ways in the docs to access that field so I'm guessing it's at the classes since adding the boolean property to the Author class itself works.

BaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private boolean isNew;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }
```

template

```
<div class="container">
    <form th:object="${author}" method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="...">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        **<button th:text="${author['isNew']} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>**
    </form>
</div>
```

Expressions I've tried

```
<button th:text="${author['isNew']} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
<button th:text="${author['isNew']} == true ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
<button th:text="${author['new']} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
<button th:text="${author['new']} == true ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
<button th:text="${author.isNew()} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
<button th:text="${author.isNew} == true ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
<button th:with="text=${author['new']} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" th:text="${text}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
```

**Update**

I've tinkered around with more EL expressions and got to these results below. This could mean to me that thymeleaf isn't processing the ternary operator correctly for bool `id == null`.

```
<button th:with="text=${author.id} > 0" th:text="${text}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>  //true

<button th:with="text=${author.id} == null" th:text="${text}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button> //false
```

The expression that worked doesn't involve reading the field making it redundant:

```
<button th:with="text=${author.id} == null" th:text="${text} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
```

If you know a solution to this please PM/Comment!
An example project where its working is:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model/BaseEntity.java

Comment: Pretty sure thymeleaf names are relative to get functions and `get` or `is` is trimmed so it would be `<button th:text="${author.new} ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>`, personally i would avoid using variable names that conflict with keywords like `new`, 
Can also use `*{new}` instead of `${author.new}` as you set the object on form

Comment: @Ralan `*{isNew}` or `${author['new']}` evaluates fine, `*{new}` leads to EL error, but doesn't properly find the true value of the object for update. !isNew since it's in the repository already with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put everything inside the ${} to let thyme leaf understand the expression

```html
<button th:text="${author.isNew() ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
```

Comment: I've tried so but still not working.
 ```
       <button th:text="${author['isNew'] ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
        <button th:text="${author['isNew'] == true ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
        <button th:text="${author['new'] ? 'Create New Author' : 'Update Author'}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Process</button>
```